# replacing a vm with raspberry pi( copying the libraries and files)

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, raspberry-pi

Hi i have a VM on which i was doing my development. 
now i have a situation in which i should run copies of that vm in different buildings.
so i thought of getting a raspberry pi and running my programs on them in each building.

i have around 50 buildings and installing all the libraries and copying all those files into so many individual machines would be tough.. so **is there any way where we can copy all those files(installed libraries and files present in my vm) into my raspberry pi**?

i tried searching on google but nothing came up.

Thanks

Comment: *"is there any way where we can copy all those files ... into my raspberry pi?'* -- You mention **one** VM and **my** (or just one) RaspberryPi, but complain about *"50 buildings"* and *"so many individual machines"*.  Why are there *"so many individual machines"* but only one RPi?  Are you considering *"getting **a** raspberry pi"* or 50 RPi?

Comment: @sawdust right now i have only 4 of them but i'll have to get 50 installed

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly not in their present form, since the raspberry pi is most likely a different architecture than the VM. If you set one pi up manually though, it's very easy to duplicate it by imaging the SD card.

Comment: yes! i was doing that. but when the number of raspberry pi's increased to 50, i just wanted to know if there's a possibility.

Thanks.